# Stats Extension: No stats.jar file

Tags: netlogo

Has anyone tried to use the latest stats extension 1.3.1?  I have tried, but when I unzip the file there is no stats.jar or stats.jar.gz files, like there was in the 1.2.1 version.  If you have used it how did you get it to work?

I need it because it has a beta distribution function and is also easier to get up an running than the R extension (I have a locked down system).

Answer (score 2):

The stats.jar file was missing from release v1.3.1. There is now a new release, v1.3.2, that contains stats.jar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the jars have not been packaged with the currently available release at https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension/releases/tag/v1.3.1.

This is most likely a simple oversight from the author. I have opened [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension/issues/2).

In the meanwhile, you can still [get an old jar from the git archive](https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension/blob/4a47f559465051959746dd64c3f6186b4dea0724/StatsExtension-v1.3.1.zip) or [try to build the extension yourself](https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension#building).